# Barebones add_filter example doesn't work... what's wrong here?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've never used my own Wordpress filters before, so I was trying to understand how it's done.

I created a simple example that seems like it should work, but it doesn't. I expect it to echo 'filtered', but it echoes 'unfiltered'. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function test() {
  $stuff = 'unfiltered';
  apply_filters('test',$stuff);
  echo $stuff;
}

add_filter('test',function() {
  return 'filtered';
});

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhhhh. Silly mistake. I needed to assign apply_filter to a variable before echoing it.